# How to extend tinyMCE table plugin

Tags: javascript, tinymce

Is there a way for tinyMCE table plugin to be extended so that the template table will have a default 200px width on its first column? I am using inlite theme and I would like to have the default table template be like below by default:

```
<table>
   <tr>
     <td width='200px'>First columns will have 200px width by default</td>
     <td></td>
   </tr>
</table>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For anyone who might be having this problem, the BeforeSetContent event can be used to get the inserted table. [https://www.tinymce.com/docs/advanced/events/#beforesetcontent][1]

```
tinymce.init({
        selector: '.tinymce' ,
        theme: 'inlite',
        plugins: 'table',
        insert_toolbar: 'quicktable',
        table_appearance_options: true,
        selection_toolbar: 'bold italic underline',
        nonbreaking_force_tab: true,
        inline: true,
        init_instance_callback: function (editor) {
            editor.on('BeforeSetContent', function (e) {
                if(e.content.indexOf('<td>')){
                    e.content = e.content.replace(/<td>/, "<td width='200'>");
                }
            });
        }
    });
```